# How can I use Fancybox for a rotating image div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to get Fancybox ([http://fancybox.net/howto](http://fancybox.net/)) to work for the dailyimg div (see the HTML snippet below) to enlarge the image. The div contains a single image that is rotated daily (see the JavaScript that follows). I'm not sure how to get the Fancybox working. Any help would be much appreciated. -M

```
<div id="emma2011_left">
<h2>Image of the Day</h2>
<div id="dImg">
<a id="inline" href="#dailyimg"><div id="dailyimg" class="feature"></div></a>
<div id="title" class="feature"></div>
<div id="caption" class="feature"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
oImages = [
{time: '2011-8-28', img: 'images/rotation_pics/test_pic.jpg', title: "testpic title", caption:  "my caption" },
time: '2011-8-29', img: 'images/rotation_pics/test_pic2.jpg', title: "testpic title", caption: "my caption" }
];

var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

window.onload = function(){
for(var i in oImages){
    if(oImages[i].time == today) oTodayImage = oImages[i];
}

oImg = document.createElement("img");
oImg.setAttribute("title", oTodayImage.title);
oImg.setAttribute("src", oTodayImage.img);
var e = document.getElementById("dailyimg");
e.appendChild(oImg);

var title=document.createTextNode(oTodayImage.title);
var f = document.getElementById("title");
f.appendChild(title);

var capt=document.createTextNode(oTodayImage.caption);
var g = document.getElementById("caption");
g.appendChild(capt);

$("a#inline").fancybox({
'overlayShow': false,
'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
});
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only basic debugging is required to fix this problem. If you use Internet Explorer you can press F12 and then the "Console" tab to see javascript errors. If you use Firefox install the "Firebug" add-on and click the little bug icon to get started.

1. The 13th line of code is missing a brace - put it in front of the second array element just before the word "time:" like "{time:".
2. The last line of code before the `</script>` tag has an extra semi-colon and should be "}" instead of "};".

Later: Full code added below. I recommend trying to get this working using the exact syntax and file versions below, only then should you try to incorporate into your code. Sorry about the HTML formatting, best I could do in the stackoverflow editor. For the sample your root folder (2 files, 1 folder) for the sample should have three items in it and look like this:

- /default.htm
- /jquery-1.4.4.min.js
- /fancybox/[all the remaining files should be in this folder]

  `<html><head>
      <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
          oImages = [{ time: '2011-8-28', img: 'images/rotation_pics/test_pic.jpg', title: "testpic title", caption: "my caption" }, { time: '2011-8-29', img: 'images/rotation_pics/test_pic2.jpg', title: "testpic title", caption: "my caption" }
  ];`

  ```
      var currentTime = new Date();
      var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
      var day = currentTime.getDate();
      var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
      var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

      window.onload = function () {
          for (var i in oImages) {
              if (oImages[i].time == today) oTodayImage = oImages[i];
          }

          oImg = document.createElement("img");
          oImg.setAttribute("title", oTodayImage.title);
          oImg.setAttribute("src", oTodayImage.img);
          var e = document.getElementById("dailyimg");
          e.appendChild(oImg);

          var title = document.createTextNode(oTodayImage.title);
          var f = document.getElementById("title");
          f.appendChild(title);

          var capt = document.createTextNode(oTodayImage.caption);
          var g = document.getElementById("caption");
          g.appendChild(capt);

          $("a#inline").fancybox({
              'overlayShow': false,
              'transitionIn': 'elastic',
              'transitionOut': 'elastic'
          });
      }

  </script>
  ```

  `</head>
  <body>
      <div id="emma2011_left">
          <h2>
              Image of the Day</h2>
          <div id="dImg">
              <a id="inline" href="#dailyimg">
                  <div id="dailyimg" class="feature">
                  </div>
              </a>
              <div id="title" class="feature">
              </div>
              <div id="caption" class="feature">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
  </html>`

Comment: Thanks. But when I load the page in the browser, the Fancybox doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you made the two recommended changes, perhaps you have not added the required javascript and css files. Are there lines in your file, outside of the posted code, for JQuery (one .js file) and Fancybox (one .js file, one .css file)?

Comment: hi, i have all of these in my file: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: Files look good. Did you make the two recommended changes? Also, are the fancybox images, all 21 or so, next to the fancybox .css and .js files?

Comment: I made the 2 changes. Also I have the images in a subdirectory of the folder "images".

Comment: Wow it works! What change did you make? The fancybox has a close button, but it's not visible on the white border. Which option should I add/change in the jquery? i tried change the width and height of the box, but it doesn't seem work: 'width': 700, 'height': 'auto'

Comment: I was able to adjust the height, width by setting autoDimensions to false. However, that adjusts the size of the box, not the image. How can I enlarge the height and image of the image to the size of the box?

Comment: I got the close button to show up by editing the paths to the images in the CSS.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the zoom. I'm able to adjust the width and height of the box, but the image is still the same size. How do I get the image ratio to enlarge to the size of the box?